# select drop down from db query based on previous selection (PHP/HTML)

Tags: php, javascript, html

i need to populate another drop down based on previous selected drop down. please help.My code is below. Now, how i pass the previous selected value to next dropdown where clause?

```
    <td align="right">Country</td>
   <td>
     <select  type="text" name="Country">
      <option selected  value="">Country Code</option>
       <?php $result=mysql_query("SELECT CountryName FROM tbl_country");          
        while($row_result=mysql_fetch_row($result))
        { echo "<option value=\"$row_result[0]\">$row_result[1]</option>";}
       ?>
       </select>*
    </td>
<td align="right">Area</td>
   <td>
     <select type="text"  name="Area">
      <option selected value="">Area</option>
       <?php $result=mysql_query("select Area from tbl_area where CountryName='???'");        
        while($row_result=mysql_fetch_row($result))
        { echo "<option value=\"$row_result[0]\">$row_result[0]</option>";}
       ?>
       </select>*
    </td>
```

How can i set the selected country name into the second queries where clause?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to send an AJAX request to the server triggered by the first select box's OnChange event. Once the user selects a value in the first select box  the OnChange event fires, you capture the value, send it to the server with an AJAX request, and populate the second select box with the results.

Comment: could you please give me an example??

Answer (score 0):

As PHP is run on the server you will need to request the server to run the second query for you by either having the page refresh or do it via AJAX so that the page refreshes but without looking like it has.

The easiest solution would be to do it across 2 pages, if you want to do it on the one then AJAX is the way forward.

Give me a minute and i'll look for an example.